# how to check whether user like my page or not using facebook JS SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am currently working in one facebook application which is going to run outside the facebook in one webpage having functionality of like page, but on bases of like i have to redirect page on different pages,

I tried lots of code to check whether user liked page already or not but failed.

So If any one knows how to check this than please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Note : Want to do only using JS SDK not PHP SDK.

Answer (score 1):

To access the like data form facebook you need `user_likes` permission.

```
<div id="fb-root">
</div>
```

```js
var page_id = 'YOUR PAGE / URL ID';
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.type = 'text/javascript';
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
                    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
} ());

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({ appId: 'YOUR APP ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true }); 

    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me/likes/' + page_id, function(api_response) {
                try {
                    if ((api_response.data[0].name) != undefined)
                        alert(api_response.data[0].name);
                    else
                        alert('you are not like this page');
                }
                catch (e) {
                    alert('you are not like this page');
                }
            });
        }
    }, { scope: 'email,user_likes' });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get `user_likes` permission, and then make a call to the Graph API requesting `/me/likes/{facebook_id_of_your_URL}`

That call returns a data array with your URL-objects data, or an empty data array if the user hasn’t liked it yet.

Comment: @Illaya: Facebook doesn’t allow like gating any more; and with the new review process introduced with API v2 you will not get the use of `user_likes` approved for that purpose any more.

Comment: then how to get it? @CBroe

Comment: I need to know whether the user is liked a page. how can I do this? @CBroe

Comment: You can’t, because Facebook doesn’t allow this any more.